# Contar registros de una consulta agrupada en Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Hoy traigo una pequeña problematica que espero puedan ayudarme a resolver, la misma se trata de lo siguiente: Tengo una Tabla Llamada **sgservicios** lo cual almacena los registros de inseminaciones que se le realizan a una o varias serie (vacas).

| # | Serie | F. Reg. | N°. Serv. | Resp | Peso | Edad | Toro/Pajuela | C. Paj | IES | T. Serv (Días) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2343 | 24-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 328 | 10-5 | V8792-7 | 1 | 0 | 51 |
| 2 | 2487 | 07-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 10-4 | V8792-7 | 1 | 0 | 68 |
| 3 | 2501 | 08-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 349 | 10-4 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 67 |
| 4 | 2625 | 08-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 10-3 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 67 |
| 5 | 2657 | 30-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 10-3 | V8792-7 | 1 | 0 | 75 |
| 6 | 32092 | 12-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 325 | 10-2 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 63 |
| 7 | 32104 | 03-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 10-2 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 72 |
| 8 | 32358 | 08-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 300 | 10-0 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 67 |
| 9 | 33019 | 08-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 315 | 9-3 | V8792-7 | 1 | 0 | 67 |
| 10 | 33160 | 19-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 300 | 9-2 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 86 |
| 11 | 33272 | 02-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 455 | 9-1 | V8792-7 | 1 | 0 | 73 |
| 12 | 34258 | 13-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 8-2 | V8792-7 | 1 | 0 | 62 |
| 13 | 34395 | 13-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 316 | 8-1 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 2 | 0 | 62 |
| 14 | 35007 | 14-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 326 | 7-4 | EG BLACK JACK 123 | 1 | 0 | 61 |
| 15 | 35082 | 13-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 325 | 7-2 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 62 |
| 16 | 35175 | 18-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 7-1 | V8792-7 | 1 | 0 | 57 |
| 17 | 35193 | 15-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 400 | 7-1 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 60 |
| 18 | 35303 | 12-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 306 | 7-0 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 63 |
| 19 | 36011 | 21-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 6-3 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 18 | 54 |
| 20 | 36011 | 03-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 6-2 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 18 |
| 21 | 36082 | 26-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 395 | 6-2 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 79 |
| 22 | 36119 | 19-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 395 | 6-2 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 86 |
| 23 | 36124 | 27-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 6-1 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 78 |
| 24 | 36164 | 14-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 380 | 6-1 | EG BLACK JACK 123 | 1 | 0 | 61 |
| 25 | 36175 | 10-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 415 | 6-1 | SEQUOIA | 1 | 0 | 65 |
| 26 | 37105 | 23-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-6 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 82 |
| 27 | 37128 | 06-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-5 | MUSHRUSH TOPPER | 1 | 0 | 69 |
| 28 | 37141 | 27-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 370 | 4-5 | MUSHRUSH TOPPER | 1 | 0 | 78 |
| 29 | 37141 | 27-04-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 370 | 4-5 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 78 |
| 30 | 37146 | 09-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 4-5 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 66 |
| 31 | 3765 | 07-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 335 | 5-1 | MUSHRUSH TOPPER | 1 | 0 | 68 |
| 32 | 3798 | 08-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-7 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 67 |
| 33 | 3805 | 28-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 340 | 4-3 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 77 |
| 34 | 3811 | 12-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-3 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 63 |
| 35 | 38121 | 16-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 4-2 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 1 | 0 | 59 |
| 36 | 3813 | 07-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 4-3 | MUSHRUSH TOPPER | 1 | 0 | 9 |
| 37 | 3813 | 16-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 4-3 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 1 | 9 | 59 |
| 38 | 38143 | 03-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 4-1 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 72 |
| 39 | 38144 | 19-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 330 | 4-2 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 20 | 56 |
| 40 | 38144 | 29-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 330 | 4-1 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 20 |
| 41 | 38153 | 17-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-2 | EG BLACK JACK 123 | 1 | 0 | 58 |
| 42 | 38168 | 09-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 300 | 4-1 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 66 |
| 43 | 38184 | 25-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 385 | 4-1 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 80 |
| 44 | 38203 | 10-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 300 | 4-1 | SEQUOIA | 2 | 0 65 |  |
| 45 | 38207 | 16-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 390 | 4-1 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 2 | 23 | 59 |
| 46 | 38207 | 23-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 390 | 4-1 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 23 |
| 47 | 38217 | 25-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-1 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 80 |
| 48 | 38227 | 28-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-1 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 77 |
| 49 | 38237 | 15-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños |  | 4-2 | EG BLACK JACK 123 | 1 | 0 | 60 |
| 50 | 38246 | 20-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 300 | 3-10 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 55 |
| 51 | 38249 | 08-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 4-0 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 19 | 67 |
| 52 | 38249 | 19-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 4-0 | MARTIN | 1 | 0 | 86 |
| 53 | 3825 | 04-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 305 | 4-3 | MUSHRUSH TOPPER | 1 | 0 | 71 |
| 54 | 38252 | 30-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 340 | 4-0 | MARTIN | 2 | 0 | 75 |
| 55 | 38259 | 16-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-0 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 1 | 0 | 59 |
| 56 | 38274 | 19-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños |  | 3-11 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 56 |
| 57 | 38288 | 26-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 400 | 3-11 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 79 |
| 58 | 38317 | 09-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 325 | 4-3 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 66 |
| 59 | 38336 | 08-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 335 | 3-4 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 67 |
| 60 | 3836 | 16-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 4-3 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 1 | 18 | 59 |
| 61 | 3836 | 28-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 4-3 | MUSHRUSH TOPPER | 1 | 0 | 18 |
| 62 | 38500 | 27-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 3-4 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 78 |
| 63 | 38515 | 03-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 3-3 | MUSHRUSH TOPPER | 1 | 0 | 72 |
| 64 | 3852 | 10-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 395 | 4-2 | SEQUOIA | 1 | 0 | 65 |
| 65 | 38536 | 10-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 325 | 3-3 | SEQUOIA | 1 | 21 | 65 |
| 66 | 38536 | 19-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 325 | 3-3 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 86 |
| 67 | 38550 | 05-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 325 | 3-3 | MUSHRUSH TOPPER | 1 | 0 | 70 |
| 68 | 3857 | 12-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 305 | 4-3 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 63 |
| 69 | 38587 | 13-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 3-3 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 1 | 0 | 62 |
| 70 | 38597 | 21-04-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 325 | 3-2 | MARTIN | 1 | 0 | 84 |
| 71 | 38597 | 21-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 325 | 3-2 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 84 |
| 72 | 38605 | 22-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 315 | 3-3 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 19 | 53 |
| 73 | 38605 | 03-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 315 | 3-2 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 19 |
| 74 | 38607 | 23-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 3-2 | MARTIN | 1 | 0 | 82 |
| 75 | 38615 | 21-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 315 | 3-2 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 18 | 54 |
| 76 | 38615 | 03-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 315 | 3-2 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 18 |
| 77 | 38618 | 25-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 325 | 3-2 | V8792-7 | 1 | 0 | 50 |
| 78 | 38651 | 12-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 3-2 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 13 | 63 |
| 79 | 38651 | 29-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 3-1 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 13 |
| 80 | 38653 | 23-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 3-1 | MARTIN | 1 | 0 | 82 |
| 81 | 38660 | 08-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 3-1 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 67 |
| 82 | 38668 | 23-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 320 | 3-1 | MARTIN | 1 | 0 | 82 |
| 83 | 38676 | 24-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 3-2 | V8792-7 | 1 | 0 | 51 |
| 84 | 38693 | 19-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 3-2 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 56 |
| 85 | 38694 | 27-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 3-2 | V8792-7 | 1 | 0 | 48 |
| 86 | 38702 | 12-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 3-1 | SEQUOIA | 1 | 19 | 63 |
| 87 | 38702 | 23-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 3-1 | MARTIN | 1 | 0 | 19 |
| 88 | 38717 | 23-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 3-1 | MARTIN | 1 | 0 | 82 |
| 89 | 38745 | 08-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 315 | 3-1 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 67 |
| 90 | 38747 | 09-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 3-0 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 66 |
| 91 | 38803 | 16-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 2-10 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 1 | 11 | 59 |
| 92 | 38803 | 05-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 2-9 | SEQUOIA | 1 | 0 | 11 |
| 93 | 38809 | 19-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 2-10 | SEQUOIA | 1 | 22 | 56 |
| 94 | 38809 | 27-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 2-9 | MARTIN | 1 | 0 | 22 |
| 95 | 38825 | 23-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 2-7 | MARTIN | 1 | 0 | 82 |
| 96 | 38861 | 04-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 350 | 2-5 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 1 | 0 | 71 |
| 97 | 3887 | 28-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-2 | CONNEALY RUGER | 1 | 0 | 20 |
| 98 | 3887 | 18-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-3 | V8792-7 | 1 | 20 | 57 |
| 99 | 3898 | 16-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 4-2 | PODEROSO DE SABANITA | 2 | 0 | 59 |
| 100 | 39029 | 27-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 430 | 2-2 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 1 | 0 | 21 |
| 101 | 39029 | 18-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 430 | 2-3 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 1 | 21 | 57 |
| 102 | 39037 | 29-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 360 | 2-2 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 1 | 0 | 20 |
| 103 | 39037 | 19-05-2022 | 2 | Tomas Bolaños | 360 | 2-3 | SEQUOIA | 1 | 20 | 56 |
| 104 | 39038 | 10-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 310 | 2-2 | SEQUOIA | 1 | 0 | 65 |
| 105 | 39044 | 23-04-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 400 | 2-2 | LADYS MANOR MARCELLUS | 1 | 0 | 82 |
| 106 | 39057 | 06-05-2022 | 1 | Tomas Bolaños | 340 | 2-2 | SEQUOIA | 1 | 0 | 69 |

En esta tabla se puede visualizar La serie, Fecha de Registro (F.Reg), Número de Servicio (N°.Serv), Responsable de hacer la inseminación,peso y edad de la serie,  Toro/Pajuela que se utiliza para inseminar una serie.

Esta consulta la obtengo con el siguiente código.

```
    $days = 'TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, fecha, CURDATE())';
    $tserv_ini = $request->tserv; 
    $tserv_fin = $request->tserv + 2; 


    $query = DB::table('sgservs')
        ->select(DB::raw($days." ".'as tiempo_servicio'),'id_serie','serie','snro','nomi','peso', 'edad','toro','paju','iers','id_finca','fecha','cant_paju','serv_time','created_at')    
        ->where('id_finca','=',$id_finca)
        ->orderBy($request->orderby,'ASC');


        ($request->serie==null) ? "":$query->where('serie','=',$request->serie);

        ($request->fsdesde==null) ? "":$query->whereDate('fecha','>=',$request->fsdesde);
        ($request->fshasta==null) ? "":$query->whereDate('fecha','<=',$request->fshasta);
        ($request->tserv==null)   ? "":$query->whereRaw($days." ". " ".$request->operatorSelect." ".$tserv_ini);
        ($request->tserv==null)   ? "":$query->where('serv_time','=',null);

    $servicios = $query->get();
```

y a través de esta consulta, obtengo las series que fueron inseminadas por primera vez y agrupadas por el campo Toro/pajuela.

```
   $pajuelasPrimerServ = $servicios->where('snro','=',1)->groupBy('paju');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Necesito obtener cuales de esas series que fueron inseminadas por primera vez   (N°. Serv = 1) con un toro en específico, se inserminaron por segunda vez (N°. Serv = 2)**

Por ejemplo: la serie 36011 **Línea 20**.
La misma fue servida o inseminada por primera vez con el Toro/Pajuela: **Connealy Ruger** el día 03-05-2022  y el día 21-05-2022 **línea 19** volvieron a inseminarla pero con otro Toro/Pajuela. Significando esto que el Toro/Pajuela utilizado en la primera vez no fue efectivo, es decir, no preñó la serie.

Para obtener digamos estos registros hago esto,  pero se están repitiendo los registros.

```
    foreach ($pajuelasPrimerServ as $key => $value) {   
        $count [$key] = $value->count(); 
        $indice [] = $key;
        
        foreach ($value as $item) {
            $serie_id [] = $item->id_serie;    
        }
        $pajussCont [$key] = $servicios->where('snro','=',2)->whereIn('id_serie', $serie_id);
    }
```

tal como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, la información relacionada con un Toro/Pajuela la repite para otro Toro/Pajuela más la que éste Pajuela posee.

**Agradecido de antemano por la ayuda que puedan brindarme,
Saludos**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque en rigor no es un error inicializar un arreglo implícitamente, por ejemplo

```
 foreach ($pajuelasPrimerServ as $key => $value) {   
     $count [$key] = $value->count(); 
     ....
 }
```

en vez de

```
 $count = [];

 foreach ($pajuelasPrimerServ as $key => $value) {   
     $count [$key] = $value->count(); 
     ....
 }
```

Es una mala práctica porque induce a errores. En tu caso particular, éste ocurre al añadir elementos a  `$serie_id`. Si la hubieras declarado explícitamente, se notaría de inmediato la diferencia entre lo que (implícitamente) estás haciendo

```
$serie_id = [];

foreach ($pajuelasPrimerServ as $key => $value) {   
    foreach ($value as $item) {
        $serie_id [] = $item->id_serie;    
    }
    // serie ID es acumulativo
}
```

y lo que conceptualmente quieres hacer:

```
foreach ($pajuelasPrimerServ as $key => $value) {   
    $serie_id = [];
    foreach ($value as $item) {
        $serie_id [] = $item->id_serie;    
    }
    // serie ID es específico para este bucle
}
```

**Edit** para clarificar:

Se repiten registros porque el arreglo `$serie_id` no se limpia en cada iteración. Cuando añades a cada toro los ejemplares que debieron ser fertilizados por segunda vez, vas heredando de regalo todos los de las iteraciones anteriores.

Si el resultado correcto fuese

- toro A

  - serie 1
  - serie 2
- toro B

  - serie 3
  - serie 4
- toro C

  - serie 5
  - serie 6

El hecho de recorrer la colección sin limpiar `$series_id` redunda en

```
    // Toro A
    $serie_id = [1,2];

    // Toro B
    $serie_id = [1,2,3,4];

    // Toro C
    $serie_id = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

Comment: Buenos días @ffflabs, gracias por tu sugerencias, sin embargo no da respuesta a la inquietud planteada.  Saludos.

Comment: a mí me parece que explica el por qué se te repiten registros

Comment: Buenos días @ffflabs, Gracias por tu excelente respuesta haz dado una luz en este tunel tan oscuro... Excelente, agradecido por tu tiempo y tu excelente respuesta.